# nested tables, subqueries and counts

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Trying to set up a query where it will show the count of each subquery in its own column. This way I can compare them in the future to each other. When I run what I have below, instead of showing me the count for "A" and the count for "T" once, it shows the count over and over in their respective columns. Can anyone lead a horse to water on this and tell me why it isnt just counting each subquery once?

```
SELECT A.nameofresult_1
      , T.nameofresult_2
FROM table_name
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT COUNT( table_name.`COLUMN_1`) AS nameofresult_1
    FROM table_name
    WHERE booking_date >= current_date - interval 2 week
        AND booking_date < current_date - interval 1 week
) AS A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT( table_name.`COLUMN_1`) AS nameofresult_2
    FROM table_name
    WHERE booking_date >= current_date - interval 1 week
        AND booking_date < current_date
) AS T
```

[image: What the above results in]

Instead, I am trying to get it to show as:
[image: What I want it to show]

Should only be one row. What am I missing?

Comment: Because you are joining the counts on the not-aggregated records.

Comment: @shadow got it. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.nameofresult_1
      , T.nameofresult_2

FROM  
    
(    SELECT COUNT( table_name.`COLUMN_1`) AS nameofresult_1
             
FROM table_name
WHERE booking_date >= current_date - interval 2 week
    AND booking_date < current_date - interval 1 week)
       AS A

    
        INNER JOIN

        
        (SELECT COUNT( table_name.`COLUMN_1`) AS nameofresult_2
    FROM table_name
        WHERE booking_date >= current_date - interval 1 week AND booking_date < current_date)
        
        AS T
```